# Invisible virus

Tags: virus, antivirus

Recently my brother brought a usb from his friends to copy stuff from and ended up infecting my pc in the process.

I tried to solve the problem by installing kaspersky and doing a full scan of my computer on both normal mode and safe mode but no result, Kaspersky fails to detect and the virus and says the computer safe even though it has the last update.

now I can't receive any files since everytime I open a USB it's all some weird files and also I can't plug in my external hard drive because I don't want to infect 2 TB of data.

Please help me delete this virus. I don't even know what keywords to tap in google to find informations about it, I tried different searchs but nothing.

Thanks in Advance.

**Folder in USB Key**

[image: Folder on Flash Disk]

**Folder on PC**

[image: Folder on my PC]

Comment: How do you know you have a virus? Are you sure the USB drive isn't just broken?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not tech support or a virus removal site.

Comment: Instead of assuming that you have a virus and searching for that, have you searched for the **symptoms**? USB drives with jibberish names is a common issue.